# Clear validation message and error style from disabled elements in jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a scenario where some text boxes are enabled disabled conditionally.
The problem is if the elements are validated first and then disabled the validation message and error css remains intact.

I can manually remove the message and style but then we violates the use of framework.

Is there a way in which i can use the builtin events/functions from jquery validation framework to check if element is disabled then remove the error class and corresponding message.

I am using following for one of the similar tasks but not exactly the same.

```
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
    var objManualMsgId = [];

    objManualMsgId.push('MSG2');
    objManualMsgId.push('MSG3');

    $.each(objManualMsgId, function (e) {
        $('#msgPane').find('div[id=' + objManualMsgId[e] + ']').remove();
    });

    this.defaultShowErrors();
},
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLv09Let/3/) and some of the code.

Click on the validate button first and then enter value in textbox1 and textbox4

```
    $(function(){

$("#f3").validate({
    onclick: false,
    onfocusout: false,
    errorContainer: '#errorContainer',
    errorLabelContainer: $("ol", '#errorContainer'),
    wrapper: 'li',
    meta: "validate",

    rules: {
        // note: you can use variable to avoid repeating 
        // of the same code
        a: {
                    validateRequired: ['L', $('#a'), $('#b') , $('#c') , $('#d')]
        },
        b: {
                    validateRequired: ['W', $('#a'), $('#b') , $('#c') , $('#d')]
        },
        c: {
                    validateRequired: ['H', $('#a'), $('#b') , $('#c') , $('#d')]
        },
        d: {
                    validateRequired: ['D', $('#a'), $('#b') , $('#c') , $('#d')]
        }
    },
    success: function(label) {
        //label.html(" ").addClass("checked"); 
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert('successful submit');
    }
});

$.validator.addMethod("validateRequired", function(value, element, options) {

    var objCaller = options[0],
        objA = $(options[1]),
        valA = objA.val().trim(),
        objB = $(options[2]),
      valB = objB.val().trim(),
      objC = $(options[3]),
      valC = objC.val().trim(),
      objD = $(options[4]),
      valD = objD.val().trim(),
      returnVal,
        isAEnabled = true,
            isBEnabled = true,
            isCEnabled = true,
            isDEnabled = true;

if(objCaller == 'L' && !valA)
        return false;
else
    returnVal = true;

if(objCaller == 'W' && !valB)
        return false;
else
    returnVal = true;

if(objCaller == 'H' && !valC)
        return false;
else
    returnVal = true;

if(objCaller == 'D' && !valD)
        return false;
else
    returnVal = true;

    return returnVal;

}, function (param, element) {     

    var errormessage = $.validator.format('{0} can not be left blank', $(element).name);

    return errormessage;

});
```

Comment: What is `meta` option?

Comment: *"Click on the validate button first and then enter value in textbox1 and textbox4"* ~  And... ???  Clearly explain what is supposed to happen.

Comment: The whole thing seems overly complex and somewhat convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to force a validation test using `.valid()` from within your handler.  Also add a `keyup` event...

```
$(document).on('blur keyup', '#a, #b, #c, #d', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var options = ['x', '#a', '#b', '#c', '#d'];
    enableDisable(options);
    $("#f3").valid(); // <- force validation test
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/vLv09Let/4/**

You also have something very weird going on elsewhere in your code.  Since the form is valid and there are no more validation errors, there should not be an `.error` class on the element.  It might have to do with them being disabled, and you'll have to remove the `.error` class when you disable them.